# Meteor: render template inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Basically trying to get this library going, but it's not rendering the template `TableView` inside the javascript that displays a sidepanel, from the jquery library at http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-CSS3-Powered-Slide-in-Panel-Plugin-slidePanel/

```
 $.slidePanel.show({
        content: '{{> TableView }}'
    }, {
        direction: direction,
        useCssTransforms3d: false,
        useCssTransforms: false,
        useCssTransitions: false
    });
```

This just shows the text literally, but I want the sidepanel to render the meteor template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Blaze.toHTML(Template.TableView)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_tohtml), however there is almost certainly a more *meteoric* way of doing this.

I'd suggest rendering the template off-screen and using transitions to ease it into and out of view.

Comment: you mean clone the template HTML and insert it into the javascript? I'm attempting to use `Blaze.render()`

Comment: My Suggestion?  no, I'm suggesting having the sidebar rendered into the DOM when the main page is initially rendered, just off-screen.  Don't clone or re-render it, just move it into view.